# indirect with r1c1 references and App Script formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using [Kishan's](http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/p/abou.html) custom function `countColors()` posted at [their website](http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/2015/11/google-spreadsheet-count-of-colored.html) on 12 November 2015.

The custom function counts the number of cells that have the same color as the first cell in a range.  It works fine with `A1` type range references, but I'm trying to use the `indirect()` function to refer to the ranges, which does not work with this custom function.

Cell W2 has a reference to cell B6 which is the beginning of the range that should be colored.

Cell X2 has a reference to the last cell in the range.
This formula goes in cell Y2.

`=countcolors((INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]",false)):(indirect("R[0]C[-1]",false)),(indirect("R[0]C[-2]",false)))`

Here is Kishan's code for reference:

```
 /**
 @param {range} countRange Range to be evaluated
 @param {range} colorRef Cell with background color to be searched for in countRange
 @return {number}
 @customfunction
*/
function countColors(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

The custom function expects `A1` type range references and does not work with my `indirect()` reference. How do I make the custom function accept an `indirect()` reference?

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  It's my first time.  I'll try and find the one that I ended up using and cite it.

Comment: Thank you for adding attribution. But it does not look like Patrick Robinson is the author of the code. A one-minute search-click lead me to [Kishan](http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/p/abou.html) who posted the exact code you are quoting on [their website](http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/2015/11/google-spreadsheet-count-of-colored.html) on 12 November 2015. That would probably be a better citation.

Comment: In your showing script, it seems that the arguments of `countRange` and `colorRef` are not used. So, I cannot understand your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike the custom function gets references to `countRange` and `colorRef` by extracting them directly from the formula. That works as long the formula uses `A1` style range references. The OP is not using `A1` style references but `indirect()` in their formula, which causes Kishan's regexes to fail.

Comment: @doubleunary Thank you for your support. From your comment, I understood that the showing script retrieves `rangeA1Notation` (`countRange`) and `colorCellA1Notation` (`colorRef`) by parsing the formula. When OP wants to give the values `countRange,colorRef` as R1C1, I thought that directly giving the values of R1C1 as the arguments might be useful. So, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood OP's expected result, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

From doubleunary's comment, I understood that the showing script retrieves `rangeA1Notation` (`countRange`) and `colorCellA1Notation` (`colorRef`) by parsing the formula. When you want to give the values `countRange,colorRef` as R1C1 of a cell inputted formula, I thought that directly giving the values of R1C1 as the arguments might be useful. When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script.

When you use this script, as a sample, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE("R[1]C[0]:R[5]C[5]","R[0]C[1]")` into a cell "A1". By this, `countRangeR1C1` and `colorRef` become "A2:F6" and "B1", and the number of background colors from cells "A2:F6" is counted using the background color of a cell "B1".

```js
function SAMPLE(countRangeR1C1, colorRef) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  [countRangeR1C1, [colorRef]] = [countRangeR1C1.split(":"), [colorRef]].map(e =>
    e.map(f => {
      const t = f.trim().match(/R\[(.*?)\]C\[(.*?)\]/);
      if (t) {
        return [Number(t[1]), Number(t[2])];
      }
      throw new Error("Invalid R1C1 value.");
    })
  );
  const rangeCountRangeR1C1 = sheet.getRange(countRangeR1C1.map(e => range.offset(...e).getA1Notation()).join(":"));
  const rangeColorRef = range.offset(...colorRef);
  const countBackgrounds = rangeCountRangeR1C1.getBackgrounds();
  const refBackground = rangeColorRef.getBackground();
  // console.log(rangeCountRangeR1C1.getA1Notation()); // You can check the value as A1Notation in the log.
  // console.log(rangeColorRef.getA1Notation()); // You can check the value as A1Notation in the log.
  const count = countBackgrounds.reduce((t, r) => {
    r.forEach(c => {
      if (c == refBackground) t++;
    });
    return t;
  }, 0);
  return count;
}
```

#### Testing:

When the above script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Added:

Your following reply,

> but what if I want to use a cell reference for the beginning and end of the range? Example: in cell C1 I would enter a reference for cell a2 and in C2 I'd put a reference for F6? Just the names of the first and last cells of the range, but in separate cells?

Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand that you wanted to use the a1Notation written in the cell. For your reply, how about the following sample script?

```js
function SAMPLE(countRange, color) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const countBackgrounds = sheet.getRange(countRange).getBackgrounds();
  const refBackground = sheet.getRange(color).getBackground();
  const count = countBackgrounds.reduce((t, r) => {
    r.forEach(c => {
      if (c == refBackground) t++;
    });
    return t;
  }, 0);
  return count;
}
```

- In this case, for example, when the above sample image is used when the cells C1 and D1 are "A2" and "F6", and the cell E1 is "B1", you can retrieve `6` by putting a custom function of `=SAMPLE(C1&":"&D1,E1)` into a cell.
- By the way, if you want to use a formula like `=countcolors((INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]",false)):(indirect("R[0]C[-1]",false)),(indirect("R[0]C[-2]",false)))`, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(JOIN(":",INDIRECT("R[0]C[2]:R[0]C[3]",FALSE)),INDIRECT("R[0]C[4]",FALSE))` into a cell "A1" using my 2nd script. By this, `JOIN(":",INDIRECT("R[0]C[2]:R[0]C[3]",FALSE))` and `INDIRECT("R[0]C[4]",FALSE)` return "A2:F6" and "B1", and the result is returned using those a1Notations.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to use a cell reference for the beginning and end of the range?  Example: in cell C1 I would enter a reference for cell a2 and in C2 I'd put a reference for F6?  Just the names of the first and last cells of the range, but in separate cells?

Comment: @Matthew Hamlyn Thank you for replying. First, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand that you wanted to use the a1Notation written in the cell from your question. For your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual expected result again, I apologize.

Comment: @Matthew Hamlyn By the way, if you want to use a formula like `=countcolors((INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]",false)):(indirect("R[0]C[-1]",false)),(indirect("R[0]C[-2]",false)))`, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(JOIN(":",INDIRECT("R[0]C[2]:R[0]C[3]",FALSE)),INDIRECT("R[0]C[4]",FALSE))` into a cell "A1" using my 2nd script. By this, `JOIN(":",INDIRECT("R[0]C[2]:R[0]C[3]",FALSE))` and `INDIRECT("R[0]C[4]",FALSE)` return "A2:F6" and "B1", and the result is returned using those a1Notations.